# Using django RESTful api to get data and show it in a table?

Tags: django, mongodb, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using REST api to get data from a mongodb on a server. Currently I can display the data from mongodb on to a browser using django rest framework, but this data is shown in JSON format.
I want to display this data it in a table.

I am still not clear on how to use this data in a template rather than just return a response that throws data onto a browser.Do I use a serializer for this ?

A google search revealed these 2 results:

> [Displaying a Table in Django from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287027/displaying-a-table-in-django-from-database)
>
> http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#tutorial

Both the code assume that the model is defined within the Django, but I am using the REST to get data.

I am using class based views and mixins as shown below for processing http requests on

```
class RestDjango(View, RequestMixin, ResponseMixin):
    .........
    .........
```

p.s:
I am using 0.3.3 version of Django REST Framework.
I am new to REST so please feel free to point me to any tutorials/articles to help me.

Comment: if you want it in a table, why don't you use the standard view and use a template that renders a table?
i don't understand why you need REST for this things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I use a serializer for this ?

No. You use renderer for this.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer

I think the example code in the link is clear enough. Simply pass the query result as context and create your table inside template.