# Django display data in a table -- Sort of a table within a table (nested forloop?). Data needs to link as well

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure the best way to explain it so I created an example picture and made up some data:

[image: Table]

I looked at this post and know I need to use some forloop template stuff: [Displaying a Table in Django from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287027/displaying-a-table-in-django-from-database)

The parts that are throwing me off are how to have a table within a table. For example, the doctor 'Bob" has 3 different patients. Bob has one row but Bob's patient column has 3 rows within it.

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total Patient Meetings</th>
            <th>Patient</th>
            <th>Meetings for Patient</th>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
            {% for doctor in query_results %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ doctor.name }} </td>
                <td> {{ doctor.total_meetings }}</td>

                //*Would I have a nested forloop in here?*//

                {% for patient in query_results2 %}
                <td> {{patient.name }} </td>
                <td> {{patient.meeting_number }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm having trouble finding an example like this to work off of and am not sure how to approach it.

I also need those patients to link to the individual patient pages. So if I click on Bob's patient 'C755' I will be directed to that patient's page. I was thinking something like:

```
   `<p><a href="patient/{{patient.name}}">{{patient.name}}:</a></p>`
```

Thanks for any help. Just not sure the best way to approach this.

Comment: Yes, you can do a nested forloop.

Answer (score 0):

> "A 'related manager' is a manager used in a one-to-many or many-to-many
>   related context." 
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/

I can't see how your relation between `doctor` and `patient` is, but supposing it is something like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(Patient, verbose_name='patients')
```

You can easly iterate over `doctor.patient` using:

```
{% for doctor in doctors %}
    {% for patient in doctor.patients.all %}
        {{ patient.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't have a `verbose_name` attribute for the relation, then instead of using `doctor.patients.all` you use `doctor.patients_set.all`.

And to the patient's page, you can use a method inside your class `Patient` to easly do this:

```
<a href="{{ patient.get_absolute_url }}">{{ patient.name }}</a>
```

> "with get_absolute_url on your model it can make dealing with them on a per-object basis much simpler and cleaner across your entire site"

https://godjango.com/67-understanding-get_absolute_url/